# How to tune parameters using h2o DL with mlr?

Tags: r, h2o, mlr

I am trying to change some of the parameters for a `h2o` deep learner using `mlr`. Similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55914741/tuning-h2o-hyperparameters-in-mlr) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721105/tuning-integer-vector-in-mlr). However, I'm still confused as to how to change some specific parameters. I have provided a simple example below to illustrate what Im trying to achieve.

If I have some data:

```
data <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(144),
  y = rnorm(144),
  z = rnorm(144),
  Factor1 = as.factor(rep(c("A", "B"), each = 36)),
  Factor2 = as.factor(rep(c(rep("Red", 18), rep("Blue", 18)), 4)),
  Response = as.factor(rep(c(rep(1, 11), rep(0, 7), rep(0, 18)), 4))
)
```

And I set up a `h2o` deep learner model, I can change parameters (such as epochs) like so:

```
library(h2o)
y <- "Response"
x <- names(data[, -6])


h2o.init()
h2o.no_progress()

set.seed(1234)
h2oDL <- h2o.deeplearning(x,
  y,
  as.h2o(data),
  epochs = 50,
  nfolds = 3, 
  score_interval = 1, 
  stopping_rounds = 5, 
  stopping_metric = "misclassification",
  stopping_tolerance = 1e-3,
  
)
```

But what Im trying to do is alter those specific parameters using `mlr`. Normally, you could create an `mlr` model like so:

```
library(mlr)

Task <- makeClassifTask(data = data, target = "Response")
Lrn <- makeLearner("classif.h2o.deeplearning", predict.type = "prob")
Mod <-train(Lrn, Task)
```

I was trying to do something like this:

```
param_set <- makeParamSet(
  makeNumericParam("epochs", default = 50)

)
```

and then add this when creating the learner, like so:

```
Task <- makeClassifTask(data = data, target = "Response")
Lrn <- makeLearner("classif.h2o.deeplearning", predict.type = "prob", par.vals = param_set)
Mod <-train(Lrn, Task)
```

But this throws back an error. Any suggestions as to how I could change the specific parameters (i.e., the ones I'm  altering in the `h2o.deeplearning` function example above) in `mlr`?

Comment: `makeLearner("classif.h2o.deeplearning", predict.type = "prob", par.vals = list(epochs = 50))`, `param_set` is for tuning